# Angular - Transloco read in 2 scopes

Tags: angular, scope, transloco

I have a problem with transloco. I would like to read in 2 scopes in the same html. I manage to provide scope in my module and to read in 2 scopes declaring 2 read attributes.

The question is :

Can I define 2 scope in the same read ?

Example :

```
<div class="fr-container" *transloco="let t; read: 'scope1', 'scope2' ">
```

this don't seems working. What is the better way else ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read does not support multiple inputs, you can wrap multiple `ng-container` with different varaible names, so that the scope is maintained!

[source code](https://github.com/ngneat/transloco/blob/master/libs/transloco/src/lib/transloco.directive.ts)

```
<ng-container *transloco="let t">
  <ng-container *transloco="let v; read: 'nested'">
    <h1>from T Scope</h1>
    <p data-cy="todos-page-scope">{{ t('todos.title') }}</p>
    <p data-cy="global">{{ t('home') }}</p>
    <h1>from V Scope</h1>
    <h5>{{ v('title') }}</h5>
    <p>{{ v('desc') }}</p>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/transloco-example-hgmqb2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fscope-sharing%2Fscope-sharing.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)